# How to dynamically resize text within a span?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm using *twitter-bootstrap* and I'm trying to fit text (with a big font-size) contained in a *span4*.

I'm trying to change the size of the text to fits in the span correctly. In the next fiddle you'll be able to see the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/DxcQy/
Is better if you see the result here: http://jsfiddle.net/DxcQy/embedded/result/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span4">
             <h1>A</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
             <h1>AB</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
             <h1>ABC</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.span4 h1{
  margin: 10px;
  margin-top: 90px;
  padding-top: 40px;
  font-size: 14em;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #282B36;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.span4{
    background: red;
    height: 500px;
}
```

---

Then I found a jQuery plugin called [**FitText**](http://fittextjs.com/), and the I tried to use it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/DxcQy/12/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span4">
             <h1>A</h1>

        </div>
        <div class="span4">
             <h1>AB</h1>

        </div>
        <div class="span4">
             <h1>ABC</h1>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.span4 h1 {
    margin: 10px;
    margin-top: 90px;
    padding-top: 40px;
    font-size: 14em;
    font-weight: 800;
    color: #282B36;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%
}
.span4 {
    background: red;
    height: 500px;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(".span4 h1").fitText(1.3, { minFontSize: '8em', maxFontSize: '14em' });
```

But as you see, the letters are too small.

Any help or advice would be appreciated and if you need more info, let me know and I'll edit the post.

Comment: If older browsers aren't an issue, you can just use `rem` (root em), and set the body font-size to percentages.

Comment: (OT) Having more than 1 `H1` on a page is not a good SEO advice. (Imagine buying a newspaper with two different heading title names...)

Comment: Well @roXon, I did it just for the example. ;)

Comment: (Stupid question) you want font-size of A to be > AB, and AB > ABC I guess?

Comment: Yeah, that was it. I solved using other way. Thanks for all answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [BigText](https://github.com/zachleat/BigText) plugin: http://jsfiddle.net/DxcQy/17/

```
$(".span4").bigtext(
{
    childSelector: '> h1'
});
```

Result: 
[image]

Comment: Yes I would use this plugin over FitText. A quick look at FitTexts source reveals it just sets the font size to (width of element)/100 and since h1 tags are block their widths will always be equal.